# accidentally disabled my localhost dashboard on wordpress by overriding my SSL certificate in one of the SSL plugins

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

I accidentally disabled my localhost dashboard on wordpress by overriding my SSL certificate in one of the SSL plugins. so right night my dashboard and page is not loading at all only saying “ssl peotocol error”. I dont know where can I fix it as it disabled the whole page so i can not go to the dashboard settings. Any ideas?

I was in this SSL plugin and was trying to set up the ssl certificate locally although i am not sure if is possible till my page is on localhost, but anyways as the plugin settings was shewing me some errors and there was a bottom to enable SSL override, I clicked on that, I thought it will fix it but then the whole page went off and dont know where can I fix it if is not opening or login.